# How to get the latest solution stack from elasticbeanstalk after the specific version of solutiuon stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to find the solution stack released after the specific version by AWS in elasticbeanstalk.

for instance: Lets consider i am using "64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v4.4.6 running Node.js" currently this is the latest solution stack from node JS and linux flavour some days ago.

I want to find if there is any other latest version released after this version or not ?

How do i get that via API or any other way ? Is there a way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `aws elasticbeanstalk list-available-solution-stacks` CLI command to get the list of available solution stacks. Give the `--region` as a parameter to get the region specific solution stacks.

Using Java to get the available solution stacks

```
AWSElasticBeanstalk client = AWSElasticBeanstalkClientBuilder.standard().build();
ListAvailableSolutionStacksRequest request = new ListAvailableSolutionStacksRequest();
ListAvailableSolutionStacksResult response = client.listAvailableSolutionStacks(request);
```

The endpoint to get the solution stacks [https://elasticbeanstalk.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?Operation=ListAvailableSolutionStacks
&AuthParams](https://elasticbeanstalk.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?Operation=ListAvailableSolutionStacks%20&AuthParams)

For more see [list-available-solution-stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/list-available-solution-stacks.html)

Comment: yes i am doing the same Vaisakh. My question is i only want the list of solution stack after the version which i am using currently.Example : "64bit Amazon Linux 2017.09 v4.4.6 running Node.js" this is my current solution stack which i want to give as input, and i should get only the list of higher versions of the same flavour.

Comment: That's the custom one that you have to create. I don't think there is such an API which returns the latest by getting the solution stack as input.

Comment: I tried most of the logics to get this. Nothing is getting stabled. wanted to know wheather someone cracked this out ???

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the latest version is always highest in the list, this works:

`aws elasticbeanstalk list-available-solution-stacks --region eu-west-1 --query SolutionStacks --output text |tr '\t' '\n'|grep 'Node.js'|head -n 1`

Comment: Unfortunately it's not: `"SolutionStackName": "64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.6 running Docker 1.11.2",
            "SolutionStackName": "64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v2.18.0 running Multi-container Docker 18.09.9-ce (Generic)",`